# Sharing baseline between canvas text and html element

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, vertical-alignment

I'm drawing some text to a HTML canvas element, and next to that text I have a plain CSS-styled and absolutely positioned HTML button, with the position computed by JavaScript. I'd like to use the same font for both, which seems easy, and I'd also like both to share the same baseline. Which, as far as I can tell, is really hard at the moment, at least given the set of constraints I'm facing.

- Out of the box, the canvas-drawn text uses [`textBaseline = 'alphabetic'`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/textBaseline), and I can't change that (for compatibility reasons and to get basline-aligned text using different fonts within the canvas). On the other hand, absolute positioning on the HTML element uses the top or bottom margin, but not the baseline.
- The [`TextMetrics` documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextMetrics) describes various vertical measurements, but points out that they are only available on Chrome and even there only after some flag has been set. I need something that works on a decent percentage (say >80%) of current browsers.
- I don't know what font will be used, so hard-coding some metric information about the font is not an option.

So what options do I have?

1. Do I have to render the font to a second off-screen canvas and [examine its pixel data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15649357/1468366) in order to find the actual dimensions? Can I even trust that these actual dimensions, as computed from marked pixel on the canvas, match the dimensions used to compute the size of the button even for some of the more artistic fonts?
2. Do I need to [resort to a spacer image](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20445421/1468366)? By the way, the main difference between my question and [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20443220/1468366) is probably the fact that I'm doing the positioning in JavaScript, so I don't need a pure CSS solution, and I can use what help a canvas can give me.
3. Is there some other (i.e. without spacer image) way to leverage the `vertical-align` CSS property, by creating some outer box with a well-defined baseline and then nesting the button inside that aligned to the same baseline?
4. Any other direction I could take?

Comment: Clearly this is old but if you can change the `textBaseline` property to "middle", you can align them very well. You just need to get the line-height css property of the button. Then you can calculate the `y` for where to draw your text on canvas like this: `var y = cssLineHeight / 2`. I discovered this in making this lib: https://inorganik.github.io/strokeText.js/

Answer (score 2):

There might be a way using canvas ability to draw svg on canvas, and the more developed [`<text>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/text) and other text-related elements from SVG.

But, this solution is far from being perfect and has a lot of caveats, but we'll come to it after this small example :

```js
function basedLineText(canvasStr, ctx, HTMLStr, HTMLContainer, baseline, x, y, font) {
  // create our svg elements
  var svgNS = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';
  var svg = document.createElementNS(svgNS, 'svg');
  var txt = document.createElementNS(svgNS, 'text');
  var tspan = document.createElementNS(svgNS, 'tspan');

  txt.setAttribute('dominant-baseline', baseline);
  txt.setAttribute('x', x);
  txt.setAttribute('y', y);

  tspan.setAttribute('style', 'font:' + font);

  txt.appendChild(tspan);
  svg.appendChild(txt);

  // we will first deal with the canvas part
  tspan.textContent = canvasStr;

  // we need to append it in the doc to get its BoundingBox
  HTMLContainer.appendChild(svg);

  // remove the whitespace around our text
  var bB = svg.getBBox();
  svg.setAttribute('viewBox', bB.x + ',' + bB.y + ',' + bB.width + ',' + bB.height);
  svg.setAttribute('width', bB.width);
  svg.setAttribute('height', bB.height);

  // get the end x position of our text
  var left = txt.getBoundingClientRect().right;

  // draw it to the canvas
  var svgData = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svg);
  var img = new Image();
  img.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(this, x, y);
  };
  img.src = 'data:image/svg+xml; charset=utf8, ' + encodeURIComponent(svgData);

  // now the HTML side
  tspan.textContent = HTMLStr;

  // text size probably has changed
  var bB = svg.getBBox();
  svg.setAttribute('viewBox', bB.x + ',' + bB.y + ',' + bB.width + ',' + bB.height);
  svg.setAttribute('width', bB.width);
  svg.setAttribute('height', bB.height);

  // move our absolutely positioned container
  HTMLContainer.style.top = y + 'px';
  HTMLContainer.style.left = (x + left) + 'px';
}

var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
basedLineText('hello', ctx, ' world', tst1, 'alphabetic', 20, 20, '12px "sans serif"');
basedLineText('hello', ctx, ' world', tst2, 'middle', 20, 60, '32px monospace');
basedLineText('hello', ctx, ' world', tst3, 'hanging', 20, 80, '64px cursive');
```

```css
div,
canvas {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0px;
}

/* only html content is affected */
div {
  fill: green;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
<div id="tst1"></div>
<div id="tst2"></div>
<div id="tst3"></div>
```

So now, the caveats :

- **Cross-browser status** :
  Basic rendering should be supported in all modern browsers (IE>=9), but some early versions of FF couldn't draw SVG to canvas, but still, it should be higher than your 80% request (I consider it as 80% of browsers supporting canvas btw). 
  But if you need to export the canvas, or simply access its imageData, then the ratio goes down : IE
- **Which fonts can be used** : 
  That may be the biggest limitation : When drawing an svg to the canvas, we need to pass it to an HTMLImageElement first. Browsers are afraid of this element, and for security reasons, no external resources can be requested from the inner document. For our case, this does mean that if you want to include a font that is not in the user's system fonts library, you'll have to include it as a dataURI in the svg element.
- **Ease of use** :
  The function I wrote is really specific for this example and I don't think it will fit any other case, nor yours.

Comment: This is an interesting approach. I hadn't considered [the `getBBox` method](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/types.html#__svg__SVGLocatable__getBBox) of SVG. I wonder whether I could make do without the draw-image-to-canvas step, by using SVG to measure the text that I'm about to draw to canvas. Will need some experimenting, but this sounds like yet another option.

Comment: unfortunately, I don't think canvas texts methods and svg ones are similar enough in all UAs to avoid the drawImage part

Answer (score 1):

You could have added that the metrics would differ slightly depending on the different browser's text render engine.

Text is difficult and not easy to get right without the low-level metrics. And as you state they are currently only available in Chrome under experimental flags.

> 4. Any other direction I could take?

You can read and parse the fonts manually and obtain metrics from that. There is **[this (Font.js)](https://github.com/pomax/Font.js/)** solution as well as **[this one (OpenType.js)](https://github.com/nodebox/opentype.js)** to help doing that. This will in turn though limit types of fonts you can use.

The other approach is to simply create the button using a second canvas element. You can still receive click events etc. but now you would have the same conditions for the font as in the main canvas.